# How can we design the communication flows? Is there any tool for that?

Tags: tools, workflow, user-communication, task-flow

I am writing this question to user experience since I believe that service design is highly related with user experience field.

I searched for finding a tool for designing the communications of a service like:

- Sending an e-mail when a user is registered
- Sending an SMS when somebody tries to enter to the account with wrong password
- Sending an automated phone call for checking if you are at home for delivery
- Having a conversation about a complaint via chatbox company website

All these actions are distributed pre-service, service and post-service stages. Is there any tool that you are using or available for designing better communications that in services? If yes, Could you please share them because I think that communication is very important for enhancing user experience?

Comment: Is it some kind of a framework or an add-on to an existing solution you're after, or is it going to be built "from scratch"? What would you expect to happen, in terms of User Experience, if you didn't implement this kind of solution?

Comment: are you talking about Flowcharts?

Comment: @BennySkogberg I guess that building from scratch can be easier since the infrastructure can be built according to the communication flow. The communications (feedback, confirmation) can be broken in overall experience of service and thus the user experience can be lower. In addition to this, a communication flow tool can align all communication style,messages in a better way and that is not a bad thing.

Comment: @Igor-G I am talking about specific flowcharts that are specially designed for communication part of the services and they are not taking one phase/action but an interconnected elements like which dialogs do we need for completing purchasing part of service? What to say when there is a dissatisfied client? so on...

Answer (score 1):

The [SMS Alerter](http://www.valuemanage.com/SMSAlerter/tabid/155/Default.aspx) (which also sends e-mail) seems to do what you're trying to accomplish.

> Alerts are generated for many reasons, among them the following: When a statement or bill is being generated, when a bill is about to be due, when an account needs to be activated, when account's activation is about to expire. It finds many uses such as fraud notification alerts. Transaction alerts, for example when an ATM transaction or a credit card transaction takes place above a threshold. Alerts can be event driven/transactional based or interactive.

Comment: But this solution is only providing SMS. What i mean is if there is a solution that can provide more communication channels all together like: SMS, Email, Facebook Message, Phone call. In addition to this, they are providing a tool for designers to arrange the communication flows and enable you select different communication channels.

Comment: @Abektes You mean like the [Cross-Channel](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/44580/what-is-cross-channel) paradigm?

Comment: Yes, exactly.I think that you are also interested this topic a while ago. I also found this book: http://www.amazon.com/Pervasive-Information-Architecture-Cross-Channel-Experiences/dp/0123820944/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top